# Quartics containing twisted cubics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

The set of quartic surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ containing at least one twisted cubic forms the divisor on the space of all quartic spaces (parameterized by $\mathbb{P}^{34}$).

I'am wondering how one can calculate the degree of this divisor.

Comment: Your $\mathbb{P}^4$ should be $\mathbb{P}^{34}$.  Denote by $\overline{M}$ the moduli space of genus $0$, degree $3$ stable maps.  Denote by $I$ the closed subset of $\overline{M}\times \mathbb{P}^{34}$ parameterizing pairs of a stable map and a quartic containing the image.  This is the zero locus of a regular section of a  rank $13$ vector bundle $E$. The direct method would be to compute on $\overline{M}\times \mathbb{P}^{34}$ the intersection number $c_{13}(E)\cap c_1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{34}}(1))^{33}$.  That may not be the easiest method, but it is the most evident method.

Comment: In case you do not already know, the divisor you are asking about is one of the first examples of a "Noether-Lefschetz divisor".  These have been studied, among others, by Maulik and Pandharipande.  So you might look at their article about Noether-Lefschetz divisors.

Comment: My first comment above was wrong: the section of $E$ defining $I$ is not a regular section.  We can understand the irreducible components of $I$ in terms of Noether-Lefschetz divisors corresponding to genus $0$ curves of varying degrees.  So, using excess and residual intersection, we should still be able to compute the degree of the unique irreducible component whose general point parameterizes a quartic surface containing a twisted cubic.